# Only the author of the comment can delete and edit?

Tags: if-statement, django-models, django-views, django-forms, blogs

I´m trying to create an if statement using django so only the one who wrote the comment can access the delete and edit icons. I tried different statements and I don´t understand why it won´t work.

I tried writing different If statements but I can´t get it to work.

Here is my statement made in post_detail.html:

```
{% if request.user == comment.writer %}
  <a href="{% url 'edit_comment' comment.id %}" class="btn btn-signup btn-lg btn-edit"><i class="fa-edit"></i></a>
  <a href="{% url 'delete_comment' comment.id %}" class="btn btn-signup btn-lg btn-delete"style="color: #fc0000;"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
{% endif %}
```

Views.py:

```
class CommentUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView): 
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "edit_comment.html"
    success_message = "You updated your comment successfully"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.post.slug})

  
class CommentDeleteView(SuccessMessageMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'delete_comment.html'
    success_message = "You deleted your comment successfully"

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, self.success_message)
        return super(CommentDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.object.post.slug})
```

model.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name='blogpost_like', blank=True)
    

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()


class Comment(models.Model):
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="user_comment")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name="comments")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["created_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment {self.body} by {self.name}"
```